# Do I have to give Git patch a reasonable name?

Tags: git, patch

I create patches to store temporary fixes because I don't want to check them into repository. I use command like `git format-patch --full-index HEAD~1..HEAD` to create patches. But when new commits are checked into repository, my patches may not apply because of some conflicts.

Now I use `` git format-patch --full-index HEAD~1..HEAD --suffix=-`git rev-parse --short HEAD~1`.patch `` so that I have hash ID from parent. I can rebase to previous revision, apply the patch and then rebase to head again.

Seems it is good enough, but people say "format-patch" can create patches that you can email to other people. If so, I wonder why I have to give patch a reasonable name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to? No.

Is it preferable, I guess so, it makes it easier to see what the patch is for.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea (it's generally a good idea to name things you do, because that means you understand what you're doing), but I think you're misusing git functionality.

For what you do, you should use [`git stash`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html). It's a stack of unapplied commits where you can leave unfinished work until you want to take it back.

```
$ git status
# dirty working tree
$ git stash
$ git status
# clean working tree - only untracked files
$ git checkout another-branch
# optional: work work work
$ git stash pop
# applies last stash to a clean working tree
$ git stash apply
# applies last stash to a clean working tree but don't remove it from the stash's stack
$ git stash apply
# re-applies same commit
$ git stash apply/pop stash@{3}
# applies/pops 4th commit in stash
$ git stash list
# lists all stash's items
$ git stash save "My commit message"
# saves stash (as with 'git stash' alone), but with a fixed message
```

This was not a usage session, just examples of useful commands.

There're people who says you don't have to stash, but you should branch + commit + reset later when you "come back" to that task. (I can't find that blog post I've read some time ago, but it was OK).

Comment: Git stash is fine itself. But I don't want to maintain a long stash list and I may lose stashes for a lot of reasons.

Comment: @echo the article said that having cheap branches and a lot of tools to play with the commit history, it's kind of dumb to use stash, that loses many of the features commits have. It's OK to use stash, but the article had some issues in favor of making commits and then resetting them. It was interesting - I wish I found it.